# Fetching reverse foreign key of reverse foreign key in django while still taking advantage of prefetch_related

Tags: django, orm, django-rest-framework, foreign-keys

I have the following models (these are simplified significantly):

```
class Job(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def get_date_details(self):
        pass
        #return a list of all jobdate --> details


class JobDate(models.Model):
    job = models.ForeignKey(Job, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='dates')
    date = models.DateField()
    # ... and a bunch of other fields


class JobDateDetail(models.Model):
    job_date = models.ForeignKey(JobDate, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='details')
    detail = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    # ... and a bunch of other fields
```

And regularly need to process  the `JobDateDetails` for all Jobs in the database (several thousand).  I know I can prefetch all of the data with a query like:

```
q = Job.objects.all().prefetch_related('dates', 'dates__details')
```

However I am not sure how to best take advantage of the prefetched data in `Job.get_date_details()`.  One option would be to do something like:

```
class Job(models.Model):
    def get_date_details(self):
        details = []
        for job_date in self.dates.all():
            details += [detail for detail in job_date.details.all()]
        return details
```

However, I suspect there may be a way to query all of those `JobDateDetail` objects directly.  One thing to note- as said before, I realize I can go the other direction to grab all details in one pass, however in this case I am using Django Rest Framework, and need to assemble the details as a field in the Job serializer, requiring me to go from this direction.  Thoughts?

Comment: You can try a combination of a [`Prefetch` object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Prefetch) using `to_attr` and [`values_list()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values-list). For example, your `for` loop is almost equal to `chain.from_terable(list(job_date.details.all().values_list('detail')))`.

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding what you're saying, I was under the impression that `.values` and `.values_list` were not compatible with prefetching: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/26565

Comment: The idea was to prefetch `JobDate` and then use `values()`. I just realized that `get_date_details` is a method of `Job` and not a method of `JobDate` and I am currently away from a Django installation.

Comment: `q = Job.objects.all().prefetch_related()` provides a table-level functionality, while `get_date_detals()` provides a [row-level functionality](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#model-methods). Are you trying to combine them? What is your DRF view? I would guess that it caters for a job and its Date Details.

Comment: Can you not use a `SerializerMethodField` on the `JobSerializer` which retrieves all the details in one pass, but would still allow you to specify `job_details` as a field on the `JobSerializer`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have entered some random data to demonstrate the query. Here are two options:

- The first one is in table-level, **1db hit**:

  ```
  In [23]: Job.objects.all().values_list('id', 'dates__details__detail')                                                                                                                                             
  Out[23]: <QuerySet [(1, '132'), (1, '4324gg'), (1, 'hrthrthrth'), (1, 'erhehrgnfgnmfgghmn'), (1, 'herhehrnfn'), (1, 'erg eg cvb dfg vb'), (1, 'greg egr erg erg erg'), (1, 'ewrg erg db cvb'), (2, None), (3, None)]>
  ```
- The second is in row-level **2db hits** (one to fetch the object and another to fetch its date details):

  ```
  In [36]: Job.objects.all().first().dates.all().values_list('details__detail')                                                                                                                                      
  Out[36]: <QuerySet [('132',), ('4324gg',), ('hrthrthrth',), ('erhehrgnfgnmfgghmn',), ('herhehrnfn',), ('erg eg cvb dfg vb',), ('greg egr erg erg erg',), ('ewrg erg db cvb',)]>
  ```

The second, is equivalent to `self.dates.all().values_list('details__detail')` if called from the model method `get_date_details` and can bring the following results with **1db hit**:

```
In [30]: from itertools import chain
In [31]: list(chain.from_iterable( 
    ...:     Job.objects.all().first().dates.all().values_list('details__detail') 
    ...: ))        
Out[31]: 
['132',
 '4324gg',
 'hrthrthrth',
 'erhehrgnfgnmfgghmn',
 'herhehrnfn',
 'erg eg cvb dfg vb',
 'greg egr erg erg erg',
 'ewrg erg db cvb']
```

Therefore your model method can become:

```
class Job(models.Model):
    def get_date_details(self):
        return (
            list(chain.from_iterable(
                self.dates.all().values_list('details__detail')
            ))                                                                                                           
        )
```